# Can't make font-awesome menu icon to be equivilant with neighboring menu links

Tags: css, font-awesome, drupal-theming

The first link in my site's horizontal main menu is a home-icon taken from font-awsome. This icon + it's neighboring text, both appear higher\taller than the rest of the links in that menu.

I've tried to play with the Display\Vertical-align\Margin\min-height of the elements of both of them and nothing helped...

The problem could be seen directly when you enter my site, in any page. [Here is a link to my site's homepage](http://www.benia.biz/).

### The font-icon css is:

```
.fa-home::before {
    content: "";}
```

### The main-menu  links css is:

```
#superfish-1 .sf-depth-1 a {
    color: #779573;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    text-align: right;}
```

Additional details:

This is a Drupal 7, RTL site.

---

Please help in making the font-awesome icon link homogenous in position\tallness to all other, Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
.fa{
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

to this:

```
.fa:before {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

that should do the trick. So instead of having: `.fa{}` you have `.fa:before{}`

Comment: Is there any way to hide the text and keep only the icon intact? (The text is mandatory by Drupal so I need a CSS way to hide only it --- If there is)...

Comment: Yes you can do this  two ways. Setting your icons via CSS or calling the `font-awesome.css` as external file. Look at these examples: CSS (http://jsfiddle.net/9aap48dx/) and External (http://jsfiddle.net/vtmseqku/) @user3578082

Comment: and setting the font-size for the text to 0 and the icon to, for example, 20px

Answer (score 0):

The convention with Font Awesome is to put the font in an `<i>` tag `<i class="fa fa-home"></i>` and place that next to the text.

If you can change the  tag in your menu to:
`<a href="/" title="דף הבית" class="sf-depth-1 active"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>בית</a>` you shouldn't need to make any css changes and the text should take on the size of the other list items.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a fixed line-height to your `sf-menu a` tags would also fix it.

```
.sf-menu a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    position: relative;
}
```

Then you can play around with the position of the icon, whatever size you make the icon just increase the padding on the `li.first a` by another 20-25%;

```
li.first a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}

li.first .fa-home::before {
    font-size: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: It worked but when I make the font-icon larger via .fa-home::before, it happens again (downwards instead of upwards this time)... Btw, I must ask how did you find this class? I don't recall seeing it anywhere at dom or while inspecting)... Interesting to me, Ben.

Comment: it's part of the superfish.css, located here on your site http://www.beniaharon.co.il/sites/all/libraries/superfish/css/superfish.css

Comment: But did you find it with DOM?

Comment: Ive updated my answer to allow you to change the icon size, I used firefox and firebug to inspect the element.

Comment: if my answer helped would you please click the tick icon next to my main answer please. :)

Comment: After I've seen that the icon wasn't centeralized I had to add "left: 0;" to the stylesheet. It fixed the problem but anyways the problem caused by this is the text now flies over the image. Any way to remove the text (which is mandatory by Drupal)?